# Does order of order by affect query runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, query-optimization, sql-order-by

I have a discussion with a colleague of mine. Does the following change in the order by statement order really affect query times?

It does not affect the query execution plan...

```
CREATE TABLE [originals](
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [prefix] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [from_suffix] [int] NOT NULL,
    [to_suffix] [int] NOT NULL,
    [latest] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [order_created_on] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
)

create index overlap_idx
  on originals (prefix, from_suffix, to_suffix, order_created_on desc)
  include (order_id)
  where latest = 1;
```

Will Queries A and B be different in performance?

```
-- A:
select
  ori.order_id,
  ori.prefix,
  ori.from_suffix,
  ori.to_suffix
from originals ori
where ori.latest = 1
and ori.prefix = ?
and ori.from_suffix <= ? and ori.to_suffix >= ?
order by ori.order_created_on desc,
ori.prefix,
ori.from_suffix

-- VS B:
--...
order by ori.prefix,
ori.from_suffix,
ori.order_created_on desc
```

Comment: Why not race your horses and find out?

Comment: Though your table definition and queries don't match; your table has no column `order_id` (it's `id`).

Comment: probably second order by is a bit better cause from_prefix is a bit earlier, but it anyways must make a sort, so i doubt it will make huge difference.

Comment: You already have the ability to view the actual execution plan which will tell you if a sort was done, if so how long it took and how many rows were processed. Why not start there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both of these are going to require an extra sort either way, so it makes no difference what you do.**

Of the `where` clauses, `latest` is in the index filter, and `prefix` is an equality comparison and a leading key column, so they can be removed from the calculation.

The final two `where` clauses are range checks and only one of them can be used as it's the next column in the index: `from_suffix`. The filter on `to_suffix` is going to be a residual predicate. The data will therefore be sorted by `from_suffix, to_suffix, order_created_on desc` as that's the order the index is in.

Neither this ordering

```
order by ori.order_created_on desc,
ori.prefix,
ori.from_suffix
```

nor this

```
order by ori.prefix,
ori.from_suffix,
ori.order_created_on desc
```

are in that order. Note that `prefix` is not relevant and can be removed, because it's already guaranteed to be a single value.

If you wanted to avoid an extra sort, you would need to either use this

```
order by
  ori.from_suffix,
  ori.to_suffix,
  ori.order_created_on desc
```

---

Or you can rearrange the index to match the `order by` that you want to use. This may mean that the range seek on `from_suffix` might not be used, but if it's not gaining much and the sort is the slow part then it could be worth it.

---

**The best thing to do would be to remove the `order by` altogether.** Then you don't need to worry about whether or not the data is in the correct order.